# Override a single JavaScript file from a module

Tags: 8

In my theme's libraries.yml file, after the global-styling section, i'm trying to replace one JavaScript file from the core Toolbar module (it's addition of padding-top to body interferes with our theme, so just changing that to margin-top).

```
libraries-override:
  toolbar/toolbar:
    js:
      js/views/BodyVisualView.js: js/views/BodyVisualView.js
```

I repeatedly get the error:

> Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\IncompleteLibraryDefinitionException:
>   Incomplete library definition for definition 'libraries-override' in
>   extension 'mythemename' in
>   Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension() (line 93
>   of
>   /vagrant/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryParser.php).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is simply that the `libraries-override` definition must go in the .info.yml not .libraries.yml:

So in mythemename.info.yml:

```
libraries:
  - mythemename/global-styling
libraries-override:
  toolbar/toolbar:
    js:
      js/views/BodyVisualView.js: js/views/BodyVisualView.js
```

If placed logically there, alongside the libraries definition, it works perfectly.

Note that the second 'toolbar' is the library name from toolbar.libraries.yml, other library names in there include toolbar.menu, so if overriding a file from there it would be "toolbar/toolbar.menu:" instead of "toolbar/toolbar:".

Comment: I updated https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets to be a bit clearer about both files in contributed modules and the location of the override definition itself.

Comment: What to do if the module / theme has no own libraries? I tried putting an empty library in info.yml but that does not include the override.

Comment: @ñull you may, but **do not need to**, [define a library](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme#define) in a mythemename.libraries.yml file.  As long as the target path given is relative to your theme root, you can make this override work just by creating the one overriding file, and the above (minus the 'libraries' section) in your *.info.yml.

Comment: When the library name contains a dot just use the full name like so `libraries-override:
  lightgallery/lightgallery.load:`