# How do I use a jQuery version different from the default one used by core?

Tags: 8, javascript

I need to use a different jQuery version. Currently, Drupal is using jQuery 3.2.1, but I need a previous version.

In Drupal 7 you could easily change jQuery version with the *jQuery Update* module. How can I achieve the same with Drupal 8?

Comment: The jquery_update module was meant for upping the version of jQuery back then, because the core version was almost never updated with the pace jQuery was moving. You could try the override method outlined here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2497313 - bear in mind that other core/contrib modules that rely on jQuery _could break_ in 8.4.x using an older release of jQuery.

Comment: Here is a similar question using the override/extend approach: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/200418/57

Comment: See the "Overriding and extending libraries" section here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add your custom jQuery library in your mytheme.libraries.yml:

```
jquery-custom:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery
  version: "2.2.4"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }
```

Then override the core jQuery library in your mytheme.info.yml:

```
libraries-override:
  # Replace an entire library.
  core/jquery: mytheme/jquery-custom
```

Comment: This only sort of worked for me. When I override the core/jquery (even with the same version of jQuery) I get a whole load of .once() is not a function errors from drupal somewhere.

Comment: Note: This answer assumes that you've downloaded the `jquery-2.2.4.min.js` file and placed it in your `my_theme/js/` dir. Also, this will not work in a module, only in a/the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Re from: [Drupal 8 theme showing Uncaught TypeError: $(…).find(…).once is not a function in console](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278374/drupal-8-theme-showing-uncaught-typeerror-find-once-is-not-a-function-i) >

This shouldn't be an issue in newer versions of Drupal but just in case anyone stumbles upon this like me: After @GiorgosK's answer I changed my

```
  once('drop-render', '.form-item-field-myfield-value-min', context).each(function () {
  });
```

to

```
  $(once('drop-render', '.form-item-field-myfield-value-min', context)).each(function () {
  });
```

and it worked beautifully.