# Custom Jquery for Entity reference form

Tags: 7, entities, javascript

How do I add Custom Jquery On-click event on a checkbox which is inside an Entity reference form?

In the below screenshot, "Study" is the Parent node. "Demographics", "Biological collections", etc. are entity reference fields.

Biological collections is a "multiple inline entity form", and is rendered only after clicking Add new Collection button (not shown in screenshot, but something like "Add new node" button)

"blood_fs" is also an entity ref field within Biological Collection content type.

What I am trying to achieve: When I click on "Blood" checkbox, I want to trigger "Add new node" button. (Add new node button should not be displayed to the user, it should be hidden all the time!)

[image]

JQuery code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".blood-div input.form-checkbox").click(function() {
            alert(123);
        })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This code does not work within the inline entity form, but if I open the entity node separately in a different tab, jquery works.

Below is the code with Drupal.behaviours:

```
Drupal.behaviors.someArbitraryButUniqueKey = {
  attach: function (context) {
    addMyEvent();
  }
};

function addMyEvent(context) {
  $(".blood-div input.form-checkbox").once("add-my-event", function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert("123");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: (function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".blood-div input.form-checkbox").click(function() {
   alert(123);
  })
 });
})(jQuery);
Hi, I have added above lines just to check if jquery works within the inline entity forms. Alert does not work within the inline entity form, but when I open the entity separately in a new tab, on click works and throws alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal, we don't use $(document).ready(). Instead, Drupal.behaviors is used, in combination with $.once(). I actually wrote a fairly detailed explanation just the other day here:
[on('load') is not working with jQuery 3?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267792/onload-is-not-working-with-jquery-3/267806#267806)

You'll need to wrap your code in an anonymous function like you did in the original code:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  // Code goes here
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Comment: HI, thanks. How do I update my above code to use Drupal.behaviors?

Comment: Please see the link I provided, it explains how to use Drupal.behaviors. Just swap out your classes and code.

Comment: Hi, I have replaced my above code as below, Please let me know if this is correct:
Drupal.behaviors.someArbitraryButUniqueKey = {
  attach: function (context) {
    addMyEvent();
  }
};

    function addMyEvent(context) {
      $(".blood-div input.form-checkbox").once("add-my-event", function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
          alert("123");
        });
      });
    }

Comment: It looks ok at a glance, but it's hard to read in a comment - you should update the original post with your new code. But the best way to find out if you've done it right is  to try it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, but with this code, nothing happens. Clicking on the checkbox does not alert anything.

Comment: You need to wrap your code in an anonymous function. I've updated my post. if that doesn't work, open a javascript console and look for errors.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much,I was so silly and had missed to wrap the code with anonymous function. It works now, I get the alert messages in the inline entity form as well. Thanks for your help, really appreciate.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working :) And it's not silly - it's programming. We all do stuff like that - it's why it's nice to have a place like this for another set of eyes!