# How do I use an older jQuery version?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript, updating

Drupal 8.5 requires jQuery 3, which has some site breaking features. I would rather like to use version 2.2.4. I have tried the `libraries-override` approach suggested in [How do I use a jQuery version different from the default one used by core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248131/how-do-i-use-a-jquery-version-different-from-the-default-one-used-by-core) After applying that answer, the theme.libraries.yml file content is the following one.

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme: 
      css/main.css: {}

jquery-custom:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery
  version: "2.2.4"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true

global-scripts:
  js:
    js/plugins.js: {}
    js/drupal-main.js: {}
    js/vendor/modernizr-3.3.1.min.js: {}
    js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }

  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

The theme.info.yml file content is the following one.

```
libraries:
  - theme/global-styling
  - theme/global-scripts
libraries-override:
  core/jquery: theme/jquery-custom
```

However, it gives me a reference error saying that `jQuery` is not defined. I have checked the path and there is no problem there. What am I missing here?

Is there any other way to downgrade from jQuery 3 to jQuery 2 in Drupal 8?

I also tried using the following code, but I still getting a reference error.

```
jquery-custom:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery.js
  version: "2.2.4"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }

global-scripts:
  js:
    js/plugins.js: {}
    js/drupal-main.js: {}
    js/vendor/modernizr-3.3.1.min.js: {}
```

Comment: Your custom jQuery library `jquery-custom` is missing the important `js` part. Additionally, you should remove jQuery from your global-scripts `js`.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz Thanks for your answer. Yes I tried that:
`jquery-custom:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery.js
  version: "2.2.4"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }

global-scripts:
  js:
    js/plugins.js: {}
    js/drupal-main.js: {}
    js/vendor/modernizr-3.3.1.min.js: {}
`
However, I still get the jqeury is not defined error.

Comment: Is the empty line between the `js` part and `dependencies` a paste error, or what you actually have in your definition? If so, remove that too. YAML is very sensitive to indents. - And omit the remote part of your `jquery-custom` library. A version and the js should do.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz That was a pasting error. I just checked the yaml file using a parser: https://imgur.com/a/JPyQKXU I didn't get any error.

Comment: Just to verify, you are using the actual theme key in place of `theme/` right?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, there's a proper theme name there like bartik.

Comment: You need to download jquery 3.5.1 min into your themes js folder for this to work. Maybe people are expecting it to be referenced to an external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with some older Google tags plugins that did not work with jquery 3.0.  You basically have to use the [D8 library override](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) methods in your theme to do this.

This actually goes into the theme info.yml file.  You need to have the other version of jquery defined in your library.yml file as well.  Here's some excerpts from my theme files.

my_theme.info.yml

```
libraries-override:
  #downgrade jquery / force jquery into header
  core/jquery: my_theme/jquery
```

The core/jquery was found by searching thru the core to find the jquery library definition.

my_theme.libraries.yml

```
jquery:
  header: true
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery
  version: "2.2.4"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2.4/LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }
```

Note: The header: true loads jquery in the header and not the footer.  Helps a bit with embedded jQuery code that complains that jquery does not exist.  I have a local copy of jquery in the js directory of my theme as well.

This technique can override any CSS or javascript included by any module or core.

Comment: Did you do anything else? I keep getting the jquery not defined error.

Comment: Is the jquery not defined coming from JS code using jquery?  If so, make sure you have the header: true option above.  D8's default is to load jQuery in the footer so js using it might look for it before it's loaded (Marketo stuff in our case).  Having it in the header loads it before most other JS code.  Also, you should be able to see which jQuery is being loaded via Chrome's sources tab in the dev tools.  This will verify which version / if it's loaded.

Comment: I used `header: true`. However, I am still getting the error. jQuery is not loading at all. I used `jQuery.fn.jquery` to find the version, and I got the jQuery not defined again.

Comment: You did not show any dependencies in your libraries.yml.  D8 only loads jquery when needed as defined by dependencies.  You may need to add   dependencies:
    - core/jquery
To your global js scripts (or specific script) to tell D8 to load it.

Comment: I have. I added this question in the forum as well with my current files: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2018-08-21/how-can-i-downgrade-jquery3-to-jquery-2-in-drupal-85
There you can see the complete file.

Comment: The dependency option should not go under the jquery-custom but rather under the global-scripts library definition.  This means that jquery should be loaded anytime the global scripts files are loaded (probably on every page).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82032/discussion-between-darkmatter-and-cg-monroe).