# Drupal 8 theme showing Uncaught TypeError: $(…).find(…).once is not a function in console

Tags: theming

New to Drupal 8.

I've created a demo theme. The `.libraries.yml` file is below:

```
global-styling-and-scripts:
 version: VERSION
 css:
  base:
   assets/css/font-awesome.css: {}
   assets/css/bootstrap.css: {}
   assets/css/slick.css: {}
   assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css: {}
   assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css: {}
   assets/css/theme-color/default-theme.css: {}
   assets/css/style.css: {}
  theme:
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine': { type: external, minified: true }
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans': { type: external, minified: true }
   '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prata': { type: external, minified: true }
 js:
  assets/js/jquery.min.js: {}
  assets/js/bootstrap.js: {}
  assets/js/slick.js: {}
  assets/js/waypoints.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.counterup.js: {}
  assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.mixitup.js: {}
  assets/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js: {}
  assets/js/custom.js: {}
  dependencies:
   - core/drupalSettings
   - core/jquery
   - core/jquery.once
```

If I deleted all the `.js` from this file, I see no errors in the console however, the images, and slideshows etc are not properly rendering.

Comment: I suspect by your comment that your bootstrap requires an older version of jquery, see if you can override it with a version lower than 3 following this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248131/how-do-i-use-a-jquery-version-different-from-the-default-one-used-by-core

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosK. kindly add the same as answer; so that I can make my vote here.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your bootstrap requires an older version of jquery, see if you can override it with a version lower than 3 following the instructions from

[How do I use a jQuery version different from the default one used by core?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248131/how-do-i-use-a-jquery-version-different-from-the-default-one-used-by-core)

Answer (score 3):

You're loading 2 versions of jquery: 
assets/js/jquery.min.js: {} 
- core/jquery

That's most likely your issue. Try removing the assets/js/jquery.min.js entry and flushing your cache. That will mean you're just using Drupal's core jquery which hopefully your plugin should work fine with

Comment: Thanks. I did the same as you said. in the console, I see there is no such error for JS however, it shows another kind of error `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3`

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an issue in newer versions of Drupal but just in case anyone stumbles upon this like me: After @GiorgosK's answer I changed my

```
  once('drop-render', '.form-item-field-myfield-value-min', context).each(function () {
  });
```

to

```
  $(once('drop-render', '.form-item-field-myfield-value-min', context)).each(function () {
  });
```

and it worked beautifully.